# Is it a bug that I can add sub interface by using "ip link add"?

Tags: linux, networking, centos

In centos 8(4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64) if I try this command:

```
ip link add team0:1 type dummy
```

I will get a message: **"RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument"**.
However if I do the same thing on Centos 7(3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64), there is no error !
And If I cat /proc/net/dev I can see there is a  sub interface:

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  eth0: 2489766199  690315    0    0    0     0          0         0 96022876  713917    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 402582904  916378    0    0    0     0          0         0 402582904  916378    0    0    0     0       0          0
team0:1:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

What is wrong ? Is there a bug in Centos 7? Shouldn't /proc/net/dev show net interfaces only with no sub interfaces?

I couldn't find an answer after doing all the searchings and googlings, to those who has a better understanding on this: please be so kind and help me ~